# How can I set up a user selected date filter for a data view web part?

Tags: 2007, asp.net, datepicker

I have a request to set up a user based filter on a list.  I know I can set up a data view web part, but I do not know what controls to use to set up the filter.  I cannot use the Date Filter Web Part because I only have the standard version of SharePoint.  I have tried setting up a DateTimePicker Control, but it gave me errors on the Data View Web Part and I have tried an asp:TextBox, but I could not find a way to convert it into a Date Value.

Does anyone have any advice or guidance as to how I should set this up?

Comment: Can you clarify where you are comparing the date value? Are you trying to parse the text into a Date object using JavaScript?

Comment: I am comparing the date value within the Filter Criteria of the Data View Web PArt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add a Textbox with a JQuery datepicker to filter the data view web part. I had to format the datepicker to display YYYY-MM-DD instead of MM-DD-YYYY to correctly filter.